# How do I ignore $1 replace backreferencing in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, backreference

I have a string that a user can edit at any time, and a regex that is being conducted on the string, to add it to an xml and then save it but they can add '$1' to the string.  I just want the text '$1' to be saved but I have to perform a regular expression on the same string that $1 is in.  It replaces the $1 with a character from the regex every time.

How do I find, and replace, the $1 in this string?

Example of what is happening:

```
string1 = '<item id="1">i have $100</item>'

regexp = new RegExp('<item id="1"([^<]|<[^\/]|<\/[^i]|<\/i[^t]|<\/it[^e]|<\/ite[^m]|<\/item[^>])*<\/item>');

data = '<data><item id="1">i have no money</item><item id="2">i have no money</item></data>'

data = data.replace(regexp, string1);
```

Results

```
<data><item id="1">i have >00</item><item id="2">i have no money</item></data>
```

Comment: its really tough to decipher what you need done here. can you reword it a little better maybe?

Comment: ah, i see. @amnotiam 's answer should do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should only happen if you have a capturing group in the regex.

If you don't want your groups to capture, then place `?:` inside the start of the group.

```
/foo(?:bar)/
```

Comment: that worked, thank you.  as i was looking at how to write a better example of what was going wrong you answered and apparently i got negated 3 times... awesome...

Answer (score 6):

If you have a variable string that you want to put in your `replace()` call which might possibly have `$N`'s in it, you can prevent the `$N` from being treated as a backreference by replacing `$` with `$$`.  Apparently, unlike other special characters in JS regex, the `$` character cannot be escaped with a `\` - it must be escaped with a preceding `$` (go figure).

In your example, you could do the following to fix the issue:

```
data = data.replace(regexp, string1.replace('$', '$$$'));
```

This should turn any `$`'s into `$$` in `string1`, preventing them from being treated as backreferences.

(Note: I found this little nugget [here](http://gotofritz.net/blog/code-snippets/escaping-in-replace-strings-in-javascript/))

Comment: Very helpful for pointing out that `$` must be escaped with another `$`.

Comment: The external link is 404!

Comment: Working link: https://gotofritz.net/blog/escaping-in-replace-strings-in-javascript/

Comment: Replace used with only a search string, will only replace the first occurence, so it would be better to use a regular expression like so: `string1.replace(/\$/g, '$$$'))`

Answer (score -1):

You can escape the `$`. Eg:

```
var replacement = '<item id="1">i have \\$100</item>';
```

Useful when you have capturing groups and need to write a `$`.

Comment: but if i can't control the content going in, and i have to search through the string for $1 to add those slashes, then i would once again have to use a regex to find all of them and i would be back to square one.  thank you anyway